# how to code an explicit specialization for a function template (bubble sorting array of strings )

Tags: c++, templates

To begin with , I am actually pretty new to c++ . I have to code a function template with an explicit specialization to sort an array of integers, and an array of strings .

> **My Main Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sort.h"

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1234, 546, 786, 2341 };
    char* c[6] = { "Harry", "Jane", "Anne", "John" };

    sort(a, 4);
    sort(c, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

> **sort.h file ( File containing the template )**

```
template<typename T, typename T1>
void sort(T* items,  T1 count) {
    T1 t;

    for (int a = 1; a<count; a++)
    for (int b = count - 1; b >= a; b--)
    if (items[b - 1] > items[b]) {
        t = items[b - 1];
        items[b - 1] = items[b];
        items[b] = t;
    }
}
```

> **The Problem is here : It says : "error C2912: explicit specialization 'void sort(char *,int)' is not a specialization of a function template"**  I am getting confused with *" char * c[] "* and how to make a specialization for this type .

```
 template<>
    void sort<char ** >(char** p, int count)    
    { 





    }
```

Comment: Cleaning up my Favourites folder ,saw this link and remembered your question. Have look at this link (Why Not Specialize Function Templates? ) http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to match the primary template signature exactly, e.g. like so:

```
template <>
void sort<char *, int>(char ** p, int count)
{
    // ...
}
```

So `T = char *` and `T1 = int`.

Comment: Still, doesn't work. Pops up the same error message .

Comment: Should be `void sort<char *, int>`.

Comment: I am using the same, vc++ 2013, but it doesn't work. Weird . :|